# My pulldown resistors don't work when connected to my battery pack

Tags: arduino, batteries, analog, pulldown

As I'm relatively new to Arduino and electronics, in general, I'm having some issues. I have a project that uses 6 analog pins. However, when testing the pins I would get random voltages. I researched why this was and I learned that this was caused by floating pins. So, I added 1k resistors to each of the pins and then connected those resistors to ground. My project is battery powered from a 12V battery and stepped down using a buck converter. I connected the ground of the resistors to the ground of the buck converter.

Although this helps, I still have between 1.2 -1.5 volts remaining on the floating pins. This problem goes away, however, when I connect the grounded resistors to the ground of the Arduino that is being powered via USB. Is there anything I can do about this? Is the issue fundamentally because I'm using a battery instead of wired power?

Sidenote: The Arduino is only connected through USB because that's how I was programming. The intended end-use will be fully "Wireless"

Thanks a lot for any feedback!

Imjur Link to Schematic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lz8R.jpg

Edit: Sorry for the bad schematic, it was a quick job. Also, each of the pins will be a different voltage when the project is finished. The schematic is just a rough visualization.

Comment: Hi Andrew, welcome to EE.SE. I'd suggest uploading the schematic here instead of giving an imgur link. People are normally lazy to go to other website to check the schematic. Further, external links may die in future.

Comment: Fix the schematic instead of excuses for bad schematic.  On that note, -1.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the longer line in the battery symbol represents the positive terminal and the shorter end is the negative terminal or ground. You might want to change your schematic. You also mentioned about using a buck converter but it's not inside the schematic. If it is part of the circuitry involving the measurements you are taking with the analog pins please include it so that we get a clearer picture of what you're trying to do.

Anyway, to keep things simple, you'll need to have a common ground between your battery, buck converter and arduino to be able to have the analog pin getting the right readings. This means you'll need to connect the grounds together.

An additional note for you:
Make sure that your buck converter doesn't go below 7V if you're using it to power the arduino through the Vin pin.

Answer (score -1):

A low resistance path to your 0V reference (battery) is essential to Arduino so that any high current loads do not share that path. Also twisted pairs for any high impedance sensing for immunity from possible switched currents nearby.

Learn to identify if errors are stray AC line-related or switching frequency-induced errors from poor 0V ref or other switched loads.

0V can be floating (or earth bonded for improved immunity) or shielded or using a twisted pair from 0V reference at Arduino.  The Buck converter itself can be a source of stray radiated noise so a low impedance ground is important. But if you intend to be wireless, then it is probably floating.

Braid wire from coax or "Litz wire" for example for low inductance is good for ground and power connections so immunity depends on coupling capacitance or impedance of paired wires and their length and proximity near SMPS.

These are part of "EMC design principles" for conducted and radiated noise.

This is just extra info in addition to the corrections needed to your schematic noted by @Zy

Comment: Another  useless voter -1 without a comment